# Trouble loading paraview module on python, libprotobuf ERROR

Tags: 12.04, python

I want to automate my use of paraview using python. I'm using Python 2.7, Paraview 3.14.1 on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. However, I am having problems loading the required modules to write the python script. When I run

```
import paraview.simple
```

I get

```
libprotobuf ERROR /build/buildd/paraview3.14.1/Utilities/protobuf/
src/google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:57] File already exists in
database: vtkPVMessage.proto
libprotobuf FATAL /build/buildd/paraview3.14.1/Utilities/protobuf/
src/google/protobuf/descriptor.cc:860] CHECK failed: generated_database_-
>Add(encoded_file_descriptor, size): 
Aborted (core dumped)
```

If I run

```
import paraview
help(paraview)
```

I get

```
NAME
    paraview

FILE
    /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paraview/__init__.py

MODULE DOCS
    http://docs.python.org/library/paraview

DESCRIPTION
    This module is not meant to be used directly. Please look at one of the modules
    it provides:
        servermanager
        pvfilters
        vtk
        numeric
        util
        simple
:
```

And then

```
help(paraview.simple)
AttributeError: 'module' has no attribute 'simple'
```

The file "simple.py" and "simple.pyc" are in the paraview folder indicated by help(paraview). I should probably note the recommended way to load the module

```
try: paraview.simple
except: from paraview.simple import *
```

returns the same libprotobuf error as described above. Since I can access the paraview module, it seems as though there is an issue with a library that simple is calling? Maybe? I have no idea what any of this means. Thanks for any help.

**Edit**

I was initially able to load paraview.simple a few times, then I received the errors described above. It tried restarting Ubuntu. A shot in the dark, I know, but I don't know what else to do. I just tried to load some of the other modules: paraview.pvfilters, paraview.vtk, and paraview.util loaded; while paraview.servermanager gave the same error as paraview.simple.

**Edit 2**

Going to follow the rabbit hole from [this link](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/1917) and see if it helps

Comment: The error must be with the version that the module loads from. When I run the scripts as using pvpython instead of python, the module loads correctly and indicates that the version is 4.1.